# How to fix css pcalendar primeng component?

Tags: css, typescript, primeng

I'm working with primeng p-table with editable cell. I try to work with p-calendar in my table.
this is my code:

```html
<p-table #pjoTable [columns]="pjoColumns" id="sinistre-instruction-ouv-pjo-table" [rows]="10" [scrollable]="true" [responsive]="true" [value]="listPjos">
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width' : col.width}">
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{ col.header | translate}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td>{{rowData.piecesJust?.code}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.piecesJust?.libelle }}</td>
      <td pEditableColumn>
        <p-cellEditor>
          <ng-template pTemplate="input">
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-right: 2px;">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 2px;">

                <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="rowData.sinpjDatpj" id="float-input-calendar" placeholder="__/__/____" name="dateDatepicker"
                  (changeDateValue)="changeValueManuelDatePJ($event, rowData);compareDataChange(rowData)" [showIcon]="true">
                </p-calendar>

              </div>

            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="output">
            <div>
              <span style="color: #0E70CA"> {{rowData.sinpjDatrecp | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </span>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </p-cellEditor>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I succeeded to implement but my problem is in the css i try to do it but i got this:

[image]

this is my style.css file :

```html
body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr:nth-child(even).ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: #abb9d3 !important;
    color: #ffffff;
}
body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr.ui-state-highlight:not(.dateFinElement) {
    background-color: #abb9d3 !important;
    color: #ffffff;
}

body .ui-table .ui-sortable-column.ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    color: black;
}
```

my primeng version is 7.1.3

Comment: may be some global styles are overriding primeng defaults. can you share the css code for the table component, global styles file and your primeng version please?

Comment: @ysf i updated my post: primeng version is 7.1.3 and i added my style.css file

Comment: i am sorry these information is also not enough to identify the problem. Can you create a reproducible example in stackblitz or github?